# Помогите с кодом, проблема в переменной 'abcd'. Ошибка Local variable 'abcd' might be reference before assigment

Tags: python

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
token='Наш токен'
bot=telebot.TeleBot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Привет')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['button'])
def button_message(message):
    markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button=types.InlineKeyboardButton('Страница моего автора:',url='https://habr.com/ru/users/lubaznatel/posts/')
    button2=types.InlineKeyboardButton('Канал моего автора:',url='https://t.me/lubaznatelhabr')
    button3=types.InlineKeyboardButton('Я подписан',callback_data="user")
    markup.add(button,button2,button3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Подпишитесь на канал моего автора',reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == "user":
        try:
            abcd=False
            a = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id='@lubaznatelhabr', user_id=call.from_user.id)
            if not a.status == 'left':
                bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Ты прошёл проверку", show_alert=True)
                abcd=True
            else:
                bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Ты не прошёл проверку", show_alert=True)
        except:
            bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Ты не прошёл проверку", show_alert=True)
        if abcd:
            @bot.message_handler(commands=['wow'])
            def wow_message(message):
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'wow')
bot.infinity_polling(interval=0, timeout=0)
```

Comment: Какого рода помощь нужна? Ошибку перевести?

Comment: Я без понятия, как её исправить. Я новичок в pythone

Comment: Что мне надо сделать, чтобы её исправить?

Comment: Перенеси abcd=False перед try. В try нужно вставлять то, где может быть исключение, а не все подряд

Comment: Огромное спасибо